# CiviMail won't send mailings; start/completed date is "0th, 0 12:00 AM"

Tags: civimail

CiviMail is no longer sending out mailings after a recent upgrade.  The start and completed dates, instead of being blank, are "0th, 0 12:00 AM".  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what causes this - but an upgrade on a site of mine (MySQL 5.5, Debian 8.9) caused my `civicrm_mailing_job` database table to not allow `NULL` values for `start_date` and `end_date`.  Since a `NULL` start date is a condition for sending emails, this causes CiviMail to fail.

To fix this, you need to run the following SQL commands:

```
ALTER TABLE civicrm_mailing_job MODIFY start_date timestamp null;
ALTER TABLE civicrm_mailing_job MODIFY end_date timestamp null;
```

Comment: This is caused by using an experimental version of the "doctorwhen" extension.  There's a patch to fix this in the works.